# I published this same idea on Sep 18 2010

Tags: infringement

In reference to the patent: [WO2015022446A1](https://www.google.com/patents/WO2015022446A1)

I published this same idea on Sep 18 2010.

see here: http://www.halfbakery.com/idea/Inflatable_20Hoodie#1284821376

how can this idea obtain a patent when I published it an earlier date?

xz

Answer (score 1):

The cited document is not a patent yet. It looks like its been filed in China and the US also. The European application number is EP20140752649, US is US20160192718 and the Chinese is CN106413448A. In this case what you have published is considered prior art and could very possibly cause the applications to be rejected. This assumes the corresponding patent examiners can find your publication. There are mechanisms for you to inform the respective patent offices of your publication. These are called "Third Party Submissions or Observations". This [USPTO page](https://www.uspto.gov/patent/initiatives/third-party-preissuance-submissions) discusses the process in the US. This [FAQ](https://www.epo.org/service-support/faq/online-services/faq.html) covers similar information for the European Patent office I'm sure there are similar procedures in China. This [article](https://www.law360.com/articles/588491/7-things-to-know-about-3rd-party-submissions-of-art) is also informative.